# How to configure the web container to run continuously so it will perform a hot redeploy using GRADLE jetty?

Tags: deployment, configuration, jetty, gradle, thymeleaf

According to [gradle.org](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.jetty.JettyRun.html#org.gradle.api.plugins.jetty.JettyRun%3ajettyConfig) :

> *Once started, the web container can be configured to run continuously,
>   scanning for changes in the project and automatically performing a hot
>   redeploy when necessary.*

Searching around I can find a lot related to maven but the project I am working on uses gradle. I have the **gradle jetty plugin** installed but can not work out how to set it to **hot redeploy** when I have made changes to a html+[thymeleaf](http://www.thymeleaf.org/) file.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
apply plugin: "jetty"

jettyRun {
    scanIntervalSeconds = 10
}
```

The `scanIntervalSeconds` and `reload` properties are inadvertently not listed on the [JettyRun](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.jetty.JettyRun.html) page of the [Gradle Build Language Reference](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/index.html) (fixed for Gradle 1.7), but the page links to the Groovydoc ("API Documentation" on the top), where you can find them on the superclass.

Comment: Hi Peter, thank you for your answer.
I have tried setting scanIntervalSeconds = 1. The only way a rebuild is kicked of is when I copy the changed file into the jetty build directory. Not exactly how I want it. Isn't it possible to watch the actual src folder?

Answer (score 0):

So, I've been looking for a way to hot deploy for a few days using the jetty plugin for gradle. I had no luck whatsoever with:

`reload = "automatic"
    scanIntervalSeconds = 1`.

Jetty checks the build for any changes, whereas the changes that take place are in src. Changing jetty to watch the src folder seemed messy to me.

Instead I used the tomcat plugin for gradle.
Just follow the usage section on https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-tomcat-plugin

Hot deployment is already configured in the plugin so just making the requisite changes to build.gradle did the trick. Hot deployment with gradle works for me now... a HUGE timesaver :) 
If anyone has been able to hot deploy using jetty with gradle please share the process... until then tomcat is the way to go